# What is the difference between IAN and LNAV/VNAV?

Tags: navigation, boeing-737, approach

Is there a real difference or benefit in using Integrated Approach Navigation (IAN) instead of LNAV/VNAV for a non-precision approach (NPA)?

Both give you lateral and vertical guidance during an NPA. Is IAN more precise?

Answer (score 6):

A Non Precision Approach (NPA) flown with Integrated Approach Navigation (IAN) is **not** more precise than the same approach flown with LNAV/VNAV. The advantage of IAN is that the instrumentation and procedures are very similar to ILS (Cat I), which is the most common approach type flown for most airline pilots. Having a common set of indications on the PFD and procedures to follow **improves flight safety**.

The Boeing 737 Flight Crew Training Manual (FCTM) says:

> IAN approach techniques are
> similar to ILS approach techniques [...]
>
> All IAN approaches provide the functions,
> indications and alerting features similar to an ILS approach. Although non-ILS
> approaches using LNAV and VNAV can still be performed, **IAN is normally used**
> in place of LNAV and VNAV **because of improved approach displays, alerts and
> standardized procedures**.

<sup>(Boeing 737 NG FCTM 5.60 - Approach and Missed Approach, emphasis mine)</sup>

The article about IAN on flaps2approach goes into a bit more detail:

> #### Advantages of Using IAN
>
> There are multiple advantages to an airline using IAN, the foremost
> being flight safety. Unstable approaches contribute to many aircraft
> accidents, and flight crews strive to always establish a stabilised
> approach profile for all instrument and visual approaches.
>
> The Global Position System has enabled stabilized approaches at many
> airports and advanced features such as IAN take advantage of this
> technology to provide consistent, intuitive displays that support
> stabilized approaches.
>
> **18 Approaches Types to 1**
>
> Through the use of IAN, the number of approach types has been reduced
> from 18 to 1, greatly simplifying the approach procedure and
> minimizing the amount of time an airline needs to train pilots in
> numerous approach types.  Time is money and utilizing advanced
> technology such as IAN can increase airline productivity.
>
> **Additional Data - Increased Awareness**
>
> The distance to runway threshold, approach guidance information, and
> vertical and lateral deviation markers are displayed when IAN is in
> range of a designated runway.  Whether IAN is used or not, this
> information provides additional guidance when executing an approach.
>
> For example, when executing a VOR approach, this information has been
> displayed on the Navigation Display (ND) as the distance to the actual
> NAVAID (VOR) - which may or may not be aligned with the threshold of
> the runway.  IAN will by default, display the lateral and vertical
> deviation, and distance to the runway threshold, allowing for greater
> precision during a non-automated approach.
>
> These are but a few of the advantages to using the Integrated Approach
> Navigation system.

<sup>([flaps2approach.com](http://www.flaps2approach.com/journal/2015/1/4/integrated-approach-navigation-ian-review-and-procedures.html#:%7E:text=Overview,Flight%20Management%20System%20(FMS).) - Integrated Approach Navigation (IAN) - Review and Procedures)</sup>